Prisma Issue with TypedSQL and Custom Output Configuration
I would like to use the amazing TypedSQL feature to write type-safe queries. However, I'm currently facing an issue because I'm using a custom output configuration.
When I tried to generate the --sql and import the query into my TypeScript file, it didn't seem to work as expected. The SQL query is located in /prisma/sql, as mentioned in the documentation.
Here’s my schema.prisma file for reference:
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  output          = "./prisma-client"
  binaryTargets   = ["native", "debian-openssl-3.0.x", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
  previewFeatures = ["typedSql"]
}


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

When generating with a custom output, an SQL folder is created in the root directory.
exemple:
orm/sql

